# Javascript check if object is in another object and match length to other objects keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I apologize for the title. I'm not really sure how to best word this as I'm still learning Javascript.

I have an object of dates that have an occurence of dynamic values as follows:
(Key = date, value = number)

```
2021-12-23: 4
2021-12-24: 7
2021-12-27: 6
2022-01-05: 5
... etc
```

I also have another object that looks something like this:

```
2022-01-05: 5
```

Basically, I need the second object to populate 0 for all non-matching keys. For example, the second object would need to look as follows (where the value of the match does not matter):

```
2021-12-23: 0
2021-12-24: 0
202-12-27: 0
2022-01-05: 5
```

I'm really stumped on this one, any javascript help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried turning the objects into an array and testing for equality. But I became pretty stumped on trying to push values to non-matching elements.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so what you want to do in order to achieve this is loop through all the keys of the first object (the one with the several DateString keys/Number values) and set the new numeric value to be 0 if that key is not included in the second object.

From your description:

```js
const firstObject = {
2021-12-23: 4,
2021-12-24: 7,
2021-12-27: 6,
2022-01-05: 5
}
const secondObject = {
2022-01-05: 5
}
```

seems like the code here would benefit from `Object.entries` which is a function that you can run on an object `Object.entries(myObject || {})` and it will return a 2-d array of the Object's `[[key, val], [key, val]]`.

So your final code will look like:

```
const mapTo0s = (firstObject, secondObject) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(firstObject).map(([dateString, value]) => {
if (!secondObject[dateString]) {
  return [dateString, 0];
}
return [dateString, value]; // assumes you want to keep the value as is when the secondObject has the value.
}))
};
```

`Object.fromEntries` is another javascript method which converts a 2-d array of arrays to an object with corresponding keys. So if you send in `[['05-10-2021', 3]]` it will return `{'05-10-2021': 3 }`.

You can run that function like this:

```js
const result = mapTo0s(firstObject, secondObject)
// should result in:
console.log({ result })
/* { result: {
2021-12-23: 0,
2021-12-24: 0,
202-12-27: 0,
2022-01-05: 5
}
}
*/
```

Comment: This was perfect. I reviewed the other answers but this is exactly what I needed to achieve. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation using `Object.entries` and `Array.prototype.reduce` but there are actually a lot of way to approach this.

```js
const original = {
  "2021-12-23": 4,
  "2021-12-24": 7,
  "2021-12-27": 6,
  "2022-01-05": 5
}
function filterObjectByKey( o, key ){
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((acc, [k,v])=>{
    acc[k] = ( k === key ) ? v : 0;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
const filtered = filterObjectByKey( original, "2022-01-05");

console.log( filtered );
```

**Updated:** The function can also accept the secondary object as an argument and filter based on its keys:

```js
const original = {
  "2021-12-23": 4,
  "2021-12-24": 7,
  "2021-12-27": 6,
  "2022-01-05": 5
}
const secondary = {
  "2022-01-05": 5
}
function filterObjectByKey( o, sec ){
  const keys = Object.keys(sec);
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((acc, [k,v])=>{
    acc[k] = keys.includes(k) ? v : 0;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
const filtered = filterObjectByKey( original, secondary );

console.log( filtered );
```

Comment: This is very clean and elegant but there is a problem where I need the second object to also contain its value. In this instance, "2022-01-05"  value must also be passed in.

Comment: I've added a 2nd version to filter based on the target object's keys @Tyler.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use some form of iteration with coalescing operator (||)...

```
someObjArray.forEach(function(x) {
    return {
        // if the obj does not have key/value pair for that date, it will use 0 (the value to the right of ||)
        2021-12-23: (x['2021-12-23'] || 0),
        2021-12-24: (x['2021-12-24'] || 0),
        2021-12-27: (x['2021-12-27'] || 0),
        2022-01-05: (x['2021-01-05'] || 0)
    }
 });
```